# Does a 15 mm high hard drive fit in the 15" MacBook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I know that a 12.5 mm high hard drive fits, but I can't find any information about whether a 15 mm high hard drive fits.

Western Digital offers a 2 TB hard drive that's 15 mm high and there's no 12.5 mm hard drive that offers more than 1 TB. So the question is, does the 2 TB hard drive fit in a MacBook Pro despite being 2.5 mm higher?

Comment: There have been nine generations of 15" MacBooks Pro, each with variations in internal layout that could affect the answer to your question. Exactly which 15" MacBook Pro are you talking about? Use the System Profiler / System Information utility to find your "Model Identifier" (your "MacBookProX,Y" number), and update your Question with that information. (I still won't know the answer, but anyone who would, would probably need that information.)

Comment: The everymac.com serial number lookup page gives specs on the space in a give model. I just looked up the Mac mini mid-2011, and it told me there are 2x 2.5" (9.5mm high) storage spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not fit, those laptops are built with slimness in mind, that being said they ensure everything is compacted as much as possible, including the compartment for the hard drive.

You will need another drive that's 12.5 to fit in there, a 15mm will be to big.

Comment: Did you try this or what do you base your answer on?

Comment: Past experience.

Comment: i also tried this with my 15" 2010 MBP and 15mm will not fit

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, i.e. 2012 and we're in 2017... but this answer may help someone with the same situation. Like rightly said above, the answer obviously depends on the model of the Macbook that you want to try this with. [In this post](http://tips.tinyiron.net/whats-the-biggest-hard-drive-you-can-fit-in-a-macbook-pro/), someone managed to fit a 15mm HDD into a Macbook Pro unibody of any size (13″, 15″, 17″) —though this will NOT work for Retina models. The result isn't ideal, i.e. the HDD protrudes about 1mm out —see pictures in the post.

**EDIT** — 2019/05: I've successfully installed a 4Tb HDD 15MM Western Digital Blue into a MacBook 17" Late 2011. The 4 screws that hold the HDD have to be removed so the 15MM HDD lies flat on the aluminum body. After that, the bottom cover goes back alright, though perhaps a little tight on the side of the 15MM HDD. Other than that, it works beautifully.

[image: 4Tb HDD into a 17" MacBook Late 2011]